# What is a model suitable for prediction of binary values based on time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, predictive-models, poisson-process

There is a time series of stock quotes, length $n=500$. The data looks like:

```
    Date        open    close   high    low     volume          Indicator
0   2020-01-03  259.18  259.00  261.90  257.77  8.962850e+09    0
1   2020-01-06  259.00  256.55  259.00  254.80  7.209356e+09    1
2   2020-01-08  256.25  255.79  257.32  254.77  6.547262e+09    0
3   2020-01-09  255.69  254.07  256.68  251.82  8.444500e+09    0
4   2020-01-10  254.00  251.90  254.60  251.20  7.220011e+09    1
```

For each element of the series, the binary indicator (0; 1) is calculated. The $i$-th indicator value $i=1,2, \dots, n$ deterministically depends on $k$ previous rows, $k << n$.

This dependence is known function $f(X(t))$, $X(t)=(x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t), x_4(t), x_5(t))$ where $t$ is `Date` and $x_j$ are `prices` and `volume`, $j=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. In the simplest case $k=1$ and one row defines the Indicator value.
The classes ratio in a sample: 0/1=480/20.

It is required to predict some characteristics like:
on what is date the 1 appear (out the sample)?,
the probability that in the $n+1$ day the indicator takes "1"?

Question. I'm looking for the possibilities of applying regression models. Is it possible to use logistic regression here? Or a Poisson process more suitable here?

Comment: Are the indicator values deterministically dependent on the previous k rows and is this dependence known? What do you want the input and the output to the regression model to be?

Comment: @frank, The indicator values deterministically depends on $k$ previous rows and this dependence is known function.

Comment: And $f$ also depends on the value of $X$ at the very day you want to predict the indicator for, right? Otherwise, you would already have your answer for your second question " the probability that next day the indicator takes "1"".

Comment: @frank, I want predict for $n+1$ day, out of the sample.